# Slider on mousewheel scroll - direction right - left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to do the following:
When the user scroll down to a certain anchor (i use waypoint) a slider should be triggered[here i have some problem, but it's not the core of my question].
The slider should slide horizontally some divs on every mouse wheel.

The plugin that i use as a slider is: https://github.com/Bawyka/jQuery-Mousewheel-Slider
but i can't figure out how to scroll it horizontally. 
Is there a better plugin? Or how can i configure this one?

My related js code is(as suggested on the info page of the plugin):

```
 $('#slider').mwslider({
    'speed':'slow',
    'easing': 'easeInExpo'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/xdwqp/

- you can add class to div, for example f-scrollable-x.
- and some js code

  ```
  $(document).on('mousewheel', '.f-scrollable-x', function (e) {
     var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
     this.scrollLeft += (delta < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 50;
     e.preventDefault();
  });
  ```

  the vertical scroll will work.

Comment: for me works everything. to scroll, the mouse must be inside the div, on the text. if you are trying to scroll outside the div, it wont work of course

Comment: There's no such property as `wheelDelta` in mozilla browsers. You need to also listen for `DOMMouseScroll` and use the `detail` property on the original event instead. This will be a positive or negative number depending on direction.

Comment: you are right. I have only tested in chrom and ie. the main solution is described in my answer. if someone wants to make it work for all browsers, he will find out easily. thanks for info